# Referenced Module cannot be found (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, lambda, module

I have defined a function and put it into a separate file (util.js) in a util folder. I then export the function within the module.

I then require the module in the main function and then invoke the function in the main function.

However the lambda console always prompts that it is unable to find the module "util/util.js"

I have tried everything I can think of and hope that you can help me getting things back on track.

The util.js (placed in a folder named "util":

```
module.exports.generateText = generateText

function generateText() {

    console.log("Function invoked")

}
```

The main function requiring the util.js and invoking the function:

```
const referenced = require("util/util.js")

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

// invoke the function in the util.js
   referenced.generateText()

}
```

**I just would like to call the function in the util/util.js file from the main function.**

Comment: Somehow it is related to the NodeJS version within Lambda. When set to 10 it does not work. Once switched to 8.10 it works fine. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

To import a local module, you need to prefix the path with "./": `const referenced = require("./util/util.js")`